# Is using new in Javascript the same as not using it?

Tags: javascript, class, object, new-operator

Consider this code:

```
function klass( z ) {
    this.a = z;
    return this;
}

var b = klass( 5 );
var c = new klass( 9 );
```

When I run it in Chrome and check in the console, `b` turns out to be of type `DOMWindow`, while `c` is of type `klass`.

Although both have the property a, effectively both being an *instance* of *klass*.

- Is using or not using new, the same?
- Is it the same on this example but different in other situations?
- Are there differences in efficiency or behavior?

Comment: Nice question, I would like to know this too.

Comment: Just from the information in your question they're obviously not the same, because the resulting objects have different types. If you investigate what _other_ properties the first one has you'll see the difference...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function is invoked like this

```
klass(6);  //called function invocation
```

`this` will be set to the global object, or, if you're in strict mode, `undefined`

As a result, the first example (without the `new`) will return the global object with a new `a` property attached.  In strict mode it will throw an error since `this` will be set to `undefined`, and you can't add an `a` property to `undefined`.

When you invoke a function with `new`

```
new klass( 9 );  //called constructor invocation
```

the `this` value is set to a new object, and is **implicitly returned** from the function—there's no need to say `return this`

For completeness, when you invoke a function as a method on an object:

```
foo.method();  //called method invocation
```

`this` will be set to the object—`foo` in this case.

And when you invoke a function with apply (or call)

```
method.apply(foo)  //called apply invocation
```

`this` is set to whatever you specify—`foo` again

**EDIT**

I mentioned `strict mode` in my answer.  A page uses strict mode if it has

```
"use strict"
```

at the very top of it.

Comment: +1, but in your second para I think you meant "`this` will be set..."

Comment: +1 All JS/ES developers must be required to have *"use strict";* tattooed in reverse on their forehead so they have a reminder every morning when they look in the mirror.

Comment: @amnotiam - sooooooo many thing make more sense in strict mode

Comment: "use strict" can be placed in a function scope also, so strict mode only applies to that function.

Comment: "When a function is invoked like this (...) `this` will be set to the global object" - this statement is kind of misleading, it can suggest that the call would actually change the value of `this`. Please rephrase a bit!

Comment: @Kos - function invocation always sets `this` to the global object, or undefined in strict mode.  I'm not sure how you want me to word that.

Comment: @Kos of course there is one obscure exception to what I said - functions created with the new ecmascript5 bind function can pre-set `this` to anything: `function f() { alert(this.a); } var g = f.bind({ a: 12 }); g();` then g() shows 12.  Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: Wow I got confused there for a second... Sorry and nevermind!

Answer (score 6):

Without the `new` your function will just operate on whatever `this` was bound to, in your case the DOMWindow. No new instance is created, the `a` property gets set on the window object. Calling the method twice clobbers the previous result.

Try this:

```
var b = klass(5)
log.info(b.a)
log.info(b == window)  // b is actually the window object
log.info(window.a)   // also 5

var c = klass(6)
log.info(b.a)     // now set to 6
log.info(c == b)  // c and b are the same
```

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely not the same:

```
var a = klass(42);
console.log(a.a); // 42
var b = klass(69);
console.log(b.a); // 69
console.log(a.a); // 69
```

If you don't call `new`, you're not getting anything new.

Comment: *"If you don't call new, you're not getting anything new."* Profound in its simplicity. :)

Comment: But of course you can create new objects without `new` in JS.